# IEnumerable<Func<T,S>> and LINQ type inference

Tags: c#, linq, type-inference

C# compiler can correctly infer type of s (string) in these snippets:

```
 Func<int, string, string> f1 = (n, s) => s.Substring(n);
 Func<int, Func<string, string>> f2 = n => s => s.Substring(n);
```

But it can't in this one [1]:

```
 var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
 IEnumerable<Func<string, string>> fs = numbers.Select(n => s => s.Substring(n));
```

To make it work one has to do something like this:

```
var fs = numbers.Select(n => new Func<string, string>(s => s.Substring(n));
```

or

```
var fs = numbers.Select(f2);
```

And the question is - why type inference doesn't work in [1] if all needed information about types is known beforehand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the information about the type *isn't* known beforehand. In your first working snippet, you're telling it on both lines which delegate type you want `s => s.Substring(n)` to be converted to.

In your second snippet, the only place where that information is present is in the assignment of the *result* of `Select`... and that isn't used as part of overload and type inference when the compiler is working out what the `Select` call itself means.

So the options are:

- Do it in two steps, using `f2`
- Cast the lambda expression in the `Select` call, or use a `new` operator as per your snippet
- Provide the type arguments for `Select` directly:

  ```
  var fs = numbers.Select<int, Func<string, string>>(n => s => s.Substring(n));
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. It's a shame that it doesn't work the way i supposed in c#. It's possible that i'm spoiled by f#, where things like let fs : (string -> string) seq = numbers |> Seq.map(fun n -> fun s -> s.Substring(n)) are possible.

Comment: @rkrahl: Yes, type inference in F# is definitely more powerful.